# Reset time after change in both linux and solaris

Tags: linux, python-2.7, solaris

In the linux system, I am changing the time multiple times using the below code in python:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

hours_from_now = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=int(offset))
subprocess.call(shlex.split("date -s '" + hours_from_now.strftime("%c") + "'"))
```

Now, I need to reset the time of the linux system back to PDT time (as was before).

Also, in case of Solaris machines, I know that similar code as above can be used except that the command to change time will be changed to `date <dateandtime>`

In case of Linux I tried `hwclock --hctosys` but the time in linux system is not set to correct PDT time (as before).

Could someone please suggest the way to reset the time of linux and solaris machines back to PDT time via python script or a linux command which can be invoked by script.

Comment: Have you tried changing the time manually? - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110529/15137

Comment: Actually I want to reset the time using python script or a linux command which can be invoked via python script. Updated the question now.